# Insufficient permission Site verification Google

Tags: python, google-api

I want to use python and the verification site api (v1) to verify website in my webmaster tools. In this example I want to get all verified sites using the verification api, because that function doesn't have parameters. (I know that it's possible via the webmaster tools, as well)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib2

from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.file import Storage

http = httplib2.Http()

storage = Storage('credentials')
storage_verify = Storage('credentials_verify')

credentials = storage.get()
credentials_verify = storage_verify.get()

http_wm = credentials.authorize(http)
http_sv = credentials_verify.authorize(http)

webmasters_service = build('webmasters', 'v3', http=http_wm)
verification_service = build('siteVerification', 'v1', http=http_sv)

site_list = webmasters_service.sites().list().execute()
print(site_list)

# this line generates the error     
verified_site_list = verification_service.webResource().list().execute()
print(verified_site_list)
```

There is an insufficient permission error:

```
 googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/siteVerification/v1/webResource?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

I have read and write access for the siteVerification api (I've checked my token here: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=TOKEN` )

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how I can debug the code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you read and understand https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/invoking in its entirety. Especially you need to appreciate:

> Verify a new site
>
> To verify a site,
>
> ```
> - First request a verification token by calling getToken.
> - Place the token on your site using whatever method you choose.
> - Ask Google to verify that the site is yours, using the insert operation.
> ```

All you need to do is properly construct two requests, `getToken` and `insert`. What "properly" means, is discussed in all detail in the docs I linked above.

If you really need help with code, you need to show a minimal working example so that we can reproduce the error you retrieve.

Comment: I want to verify sites but the problem is that my api implementation doesn't work. Because `list` has no parameters I tried that one first. Hope you understand my problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nobody understands your problem apart from "it does not work". That is not enough to help you in detail. You should edit your question and provide a minimal working example that we can look at, seriously! Start with replacing "# some import statements..." with what you actually imported.

Comment: So, you want to only list already verified sites? Or do you want to verify a new site? What is your question, *precisely*?

Comment: I've changed the description part which hopefully makes everything clear now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem...

These two lines:

```
http_wm = credentials.authorize(http)
http_sv = credentials_verify.authorize(http)
```

uses the same http object which isn't allowed.

I use this code now:

```
http_wm = httplib2.Http()
http_sv = httplib2.Http()
http_wm = credentials.authorize(http_wm)
http_sv = credentials_verify.authorize(http_sv)
```